# Semantics of smart pointers and raw pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am not sure to have fully understand when to use a smart pointers over raw pointers.

I have the following code structure.

First of all, `Snake_cell` defined as follow

```
struct Snake_cell
{
  Snake_cell(const unsigned int origin_x, const unsigned int origin_y)
  unsigned int origin_x_;
  unsigned int origin_y_;
};
```

Then, I have a `Snake` which contains a `vector` of `Snake_cell`

```
class Snake
{
public:
  Snake(const unsigned int first_cell_x, const unsigned int first_cell_y);

private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Snake_cell>> cells_;
};

Snake::Snake(const unsigned int first_cell_x, const unsigned int first_cell_y)
{
  // Create three successives cells
  cells_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Snake_cell>(first_cell_x, first_cell_y));
  cells_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Snake_cell>(first_cell_x + CELL_SIZE, first_cell_y));
  cells_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Snake_cell>(first_cell_x + 2 * CELL_SIZE, first_cell_y));
}
```

Finally, I have a `main.cpp` file following this format:

```
std::unique_ptr<Snake> snake(std::make_unique<Snake>(500-CELL_SIZE, 500-CELL_SIZE));

void func1(...)
{
}

void func2(...)
{
}

void func2(...)
{
}
/** Main **/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

Each of these functions either and some of them are **rendering functions** so they would be called a lot of time.

- access `Snake` attributes
- modify `Snake` attributes

Hence, it made sense for me, in order to avoid unnecessary copy of `Snake_cell` or `Snake` objects to :

- Define a `vector` of `smart pointers` to `Snake_cell` within `Snake`
- Create a `smart pointer` to `Snake` within `main.cpp`

Yet, I think I'm not doing it right and could use raw pointers.

- **Are my assumptions correct to use `pointers` here?** *I know we are not dealing with a huge amount of data but `funcX` will be called **a lot** of time so it might become expensive*
- **If yes, am I right to use `smart pointers` here?** *I've read that there should be preferred over raw pointers every time I'm considering using pointers.*
- **If yes, am I right to use `shared_ptr` here?** *In my code, I'm creating a new `smart_ptr` object based on `snake` object everytime I need to use it. I feel like it's not the right way to use it.*

For instance, here is one function I'm using.

```
void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < snake->size(); ++i)
    {
      std::shared_ptr<Snake_cell> cell(snake->getCell(i));
      glVertex2i(cell->origin_x_, cell->origin_y_);
      glVertex2i(cell->origin_x_ + CELL_SIZE, cell->origin_y_);
      glVertex2i(cell->origin_x_ + CELL_SIZE, cell->origin_y_ + CELL_SIZE);
      glVertex2i(cell->origin_x_, cell->origin_y_ + CELL_SIZE);
    }
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Shared pointers are used for shared ownership of heap memory. If your snake owns its cells, use a unique pointer. Better yet, store actual snake cell objects in the vector. I would recommend defining the snake object as part of stack memory in the main function, too.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you need any pointers at all

Comment: You can store the cells in a `vector<Snake_cell>` if the vector owns the cells, and then pass pointers or reference to cells to other functions *not* owning the cells. Here it feels that snakes are not sharing ownerships of their cells, and then you don't need `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: "then pass pointers or reference to cells" Should I use raw pointers then in this case?